# Same random number ruby

Tags: ruby, random

Well i'm a ruby newbie and im trying to learn with RubyKoans but i got stucked with this test

```
def test_dice_values_should_change_between_rolls
 48     dice = DiceSet.new
 49     dice.roll(5)
 50     first_time = dice.values
 51    
 52     dice.roll(5)
 53     second_time = dice.values
 54     
 55     assert_not_equal first_time, second_time,
 56       "Two rolls should not be equal"
 57   end
```

and this is DiceSet class

```
5  class DiceSet
  6    attr_accessor :values
  7 ··
  8    def initialize
  9      @values = []
 10    end
 11 
 12    def roll(times)
 13      @values.clear
 14      times.times do |x|
 15        @values << ( 1 + rand(6))
 16      end
 17     end
 18 ····
 19    end
```

the thing here is that whenever i run the code it always generates the exact same set of numbers, this is the Output.

```
Two rolls should not be equal.  <[3, 2, 4, 1, 3]> expected to be != to  <[3, 2, 4, 1, 3]>.
```

in the test im calling DiceSet.roll two times and for those two times i get the exact same set of 'random' numbers when they're supossed to be diferent right? I figured that i just might create another instance of DiceSet in order to pass the test but im guessing that is not the objective of the test

Comment: For this to work you will need to do `first_time = Array.new(dice.values)` and `second_time = Array.new(dice.values)`

Comment: I'm with you Gustavo. I'd like to save memory and reuse the same Array too. Unfortunately the designers of koans forgot that equality first checks reference, then checks instance variables. A possible fix to this reference problem is to change `first_time = dice.values` to `first_time = dice.values.clone`. But this doesn't fix the fact that there is a slight chance that this test will fail anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `DiceSet#values` returns a reference to an array, and that array stays the same for the whole lifetime of your DiceSet object. In `DiceSet#roll` you clear that array and then add new numbers. Since both calls to `DiceSet#values` return the same reference, the result of the first roll will be lost, and your test is comparing the array with itself.

I am not familiar with the RubyKoans and what requirements they have, i.e. if you DiceSet is supposed to store the values etc. If it is, then the most straightforward solution is to either use two DiceSets or use `Object#dup` to store a copy of the returned object for the test.

Be aware, however, that your test is fragile even with correctly functioning code, as there always is the chance that two consecutive rolls will return the exact same numbers. In this particular case it is relatively small but still very much existent.

Comment: The values do get cleared every time, but in the test after each roll the values are stored in another variable. There is no problem.

Comment: Excuse me? The numbers get stored in `@values`, and he uses the attribute reader `#values` to get that array. `first_time` and `second_time` point to the **exact same** array.

Comment: The probability of a false failure on this test is 1/(6^5) = 1/7776. Simply repeating a failing test a few times would fix the test to a very high level of confidence.

Comment: @FrankSzczerba But then there are tests that only fail randomly and actually do reveal actual bugs in the code. So relying on "oh, it only shows up one in 8000 times" is bad. Plus, it has the potential of false results in CI.

Comment: I agree that randomly failing tests are bad. My point was that you can adjust the test so that it loops until it gets 2 different results, with some limit to the number of loops. If you set that loop limit to 10, then the probability of a false failure is on the order of 1e-39. The probability of the hardware failing is higher than that.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work for this test:

```
class DiceSet
  attr_accessor :values

  def roll (times)
    @values = []
    times.times do |x|
      @values << ( 1 + rand(6) )
    end
  end
end
```

So we are creating new array for each roll.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use attr_reader instead of attr_accessor (like Ilya Tsuryev suggested). Because you don't want that client code cheats the dices.
And it's more readable to use rand(1..6).

```
class DiceSet
  attr_reader :values

  def roll(set_size)
    @values = []
    set_size.times { @values.push rand(1..6) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Using a new array every time will solve the reference problem that dominikh pointed, but as he correctly said that will not guarantee you that 2 consecutive rolls have a different set of nos. In my implementation I remember the last throw and loop around till I get a different set:

```
class DiceSet
  attr_reader :values, :lastroll
  def initialize
      @values = []
      @lastroll = []
  end
  def roll(n)
      while @values == @lastroll
          @values = Array.new(n) { |i| i = rand(6) + 1 }
      end
      @lastroll = @values
  end
end
```

Comment: That makes your result slightly less random. The test is broken (for the unlikely case that two result sets are the same), you shouldn't break the code to account for that, you should fix the test instead.